# Need to setup Subversion in my local box

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, windows-7

I am using Windows7 and I do lot of Java coding in Eclipse. But I dont have a version control system. I have heard of Subversion being a very popular VCS, so I would like to set it in my local box. Can you please give me some pointers on where to start/look at?

I would like to checkin/checkout files using Eclipse. Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, for local version control I'd personally suggest a DVCS like Git, Mercurial, or Bazaar - I've found them much less of a hassle to work with, especially for non-server based repositories. There are Eclipse plugins (developed by various people) for all 3: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ http://www.vectrace.com/mercurialeclipse/ http://wiki.bazaar-vcs.org/BzrEclipse (and possibly other options as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on windows it's difficult not to go with [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). As for Eclipse you can get an eclipse plugin [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

Comment: VisualSVN it is, hands down. You'll have subversion up and running in five minutes.

Comment: @Pekka, how slow is your internet? I got mine in 2 minutes :)

Comment: @Earlz well, I counted setting up the first repo and adding user roles, that can *well* take 3 more minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/ is a plugin for eclipse that allows you to checkout / in files inside of the eclipse IDE.

It doesn't get SVN set up on your machine, you'll need to install svn and set up a repository first, but the integration with eclipse is nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

If you're the only person who needs to access the repository, you can create a svn repository on your filesystem and you won't need to install and run a server.

http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/setup-svn-local-repository-step-by-step/

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is a great SVN plugin for Eclipse, you might also find [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) very handy as well. Both are very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a Subversion repository, which can either be a remote server on the internet (google "free subversion repository"), or a server running locally on your machine, or a machine on your lan. For the last one, you can use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/).

Once with a SVN repository setup, you have to install a SVN client to work with it. I recommend TortoiseSVN for general stuff, but I'm pretty sure Eclipse has SVN support builtin, so once you've setup a repository server, you just have to configure the client on Eclipse to connect to it.